# I'm seeing people playing with cards I don't have, where are they getting them?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

While playing magic 2013 in the online mode, I'm seeing people casting multiple copies of card that I only have one of in my deck builder. These are for decks that I have fully unlocked, mind you. Stuff like having two [warren instigators](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191368). I own all three games for the xbox and I haven't seen any expansions as yet, so where are these extra cards coming from and is it possible for me to get them as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is promo cards. Under the player status line, there is a link called Promotional Unlocks. You have to click there, then choose enter code and enter one of the following ten codes: 
FNMDGP
KWPMZW
MWTMJP
WMKFGC
NCTFJN
GDZDJC
HTRNPW
FXGJDW
PCNKGR
GPCRSX

These will unlock ten foil cards per deck.

Comment: So they aren't even supposed to be paid DLC, they are just "cheat codes" that you are required to discover and enter into a multi-player game?  Wow, that's pretty ridiculous.

Comment: they are actually unlocked through the single player, but the link you need to click was not talked about on the xbox version... they got the word out to all their Magic Online people, though.